# using farword slash in sql where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, where-in

I'm trying to search an element which starts with `/` below is the query.

I've already tried...

```
Select id,url from myindex where url='[/]%' ;

Select id,url from myindex where url='/%';
```

but didn't work.
any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: @Amol Solanke you can say that..Its not exactly same as my question. but why negative vote?

Comment: @Amol Solanke i have already done my effort.. that's why i have put what i have already tried.

Comment: ok thank you........................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want `=`.  You want `like`.  The second is the way to go in MySQL:

```
Select id, url
from myindex
where url like '/%';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select id,url from myindex where url like '/%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mysql **wildcard operators**. In your case try this

```
Select id,url 
from myindex 
where url like '/%';
```